# How can I fix this problem in JEditorPane

Tags: java, swing, jeditorpane

I've tried to add some HTML/CSS in the text of a JEditorPane. Also `setText()` method is overridden in this class.

When I insert more than 14 lines in the pane then run `makeLineHighlight()` or run `makeLineHighlight()` twice on the text of pane, some of the lines get deleted or I got some exceptions. When text of the pane change (I check it in a loop) then I use overridden `setText()` to make a numeric list in the pane.

As I delete `super.setText()` the code works properly.

```java
 @Override
    public void setText(String text) {

        String bufferText = "<ol style=\"margin-left: 20px;" +
                "font-family: Courier New, Courier, monospace;\"  >";

        String[] linesBuffer = text.split(System.lineSeparator());
        for (int i = 0; i < linesBuffer.length; i++) {

            bufferText += "<li style=\"\">" + linesBuffer[i] + "</li>" + System.lineSeparator();

        }
        bufferText += "</ol>";
        int pos=this.getCaretPosition();
        super.setText(bufferText);

        if(pos>getDocument().getLength())pos=getDocument().getLength();
        try {
            setCaretPosition(pos + 1);
        }catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
            setCaretPosition(pos);
        }
        lastText = this.getText();

    }

    public void makeLineHighlight(int lineNumber){
        String bufferText="";

        String[] linesOfText=super.getText().split(System.lineSeparator());
        for (int i = 0; i < linesOfText.length; i++) {
            if(i==(6+((lineNumber-1)*3))){
                bufferText+="<li style=\"background-color: #EA2A40\">\n "+linesOfText[i+1]+"\n</li>\n";
                i+=2;
                continue;
            }
            bufferText+=linesOfText[i]+System.lineSeparator();

        }

        super.setText(bufferText);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input text is `HTML/CSS`. Note that The line break in HTML is `<br />`, not `System.lineSeparator()` and you use `\n` in your new HTML code, which may be them same as `System.lineSeparator()`.
The exception due to:
 - The first time call to `makeLineHighlight`, by this line of code `bufferText+="<li style=\"background-color: #EA2A40\">\n "+linesOfText[i+1]+"\n</li>\n";`, The line number of text is increase. On of them (new lines) is `<li style="background-color: #EA2A40">`
 - The second time call to `makeLineHighlight`, your new HTML has wrong format. Likes this:

```
<li style="background-color: #EA2A40">
<li style="background-color: #EA2A40">
</li>
```

So, a possible solution is using `<br />` instead of `System.lineSeparator()`, and another is avoid using `\n` in your new HTML code.

Be aware that `<br />` is also written as `<br/>` or `<br>`...